How to store individual entries of a CSV file in variables with csvsimple
I would like to save different entries from a csvfile as variables in Latex. Here is my code
\begin{filecontents*}{DateTime.csv}
Group;Date;Time
Group 1;27.05.2024;13:00
Group 2;28.05.2024;18:00
Group 3;29.05.2024;21:00
Group 4;30.05.2024;12:00
Group 5;27.09.2024;22:00
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

% Lese die CSV-Datei ein und speichere die Werte in dynamischen Makros
\csvreader[head to column names]{DateTime.csv}{}{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname Date\thecsvrow\endcsname{\csvcolii}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname Time\thecsvrow\endcsname{\csvcoliii}%
}

% Jetzt kannst du die Variablen verwenden
% Zum Beispiel:
\textbf{Date and Time for Group 1:} \csname Date1\endcsname, \csname Time1\endcsname

\textbf{Date and Time for Group 2:} \csname Date2\endcsname, \csname Time2\endcsname

\textbf{Date and Time for Group 3:} \csname Date3\endcsname, \csname Time3\endcsname

\textbf{Date and Time for Group 4:} \csname Date4\endcsname, \csname Time4\endcsname

\textbf{Date and Time for Group 5:} \csname Date5\endcsname, \csname Time5\endcsname

\end{document}


So for example I would like to have a variable such as Date 1 with the information: Date of Group 1(27.05.2024). So if I outpout the variable Date 1 it gives me 27.05.2024.
Do you have any idea where I went wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance for your help. It is appreciated!
Best regards Roman
